# Android RecyclerView add items to top without recycler view scroll (like Instagram)

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and I want to add new items to the top of it but I don't want RecyclerView to scroll its content. I want user to look at the **same item as he was looking before new items were added**.

I tried this but it doesn't work very well:

```
index = ((LinearLayoutManager)mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition() + response.items.size();
View v = ((RecyclerView)mListView).getChildAt(0);
top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// Insert new datas..
...

// Notify my adapter
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

// Stay on the same previous position
((LinearLayoutManager)mLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(index, top);
```

What I want to do is to load old comments when user scrolls to the top (like on Instagram App).

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `notifyItemRangeInserted` method from `RecyclerView.Adapter` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged` method, to insert item on the top of the recyclerView.

```
notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)
```

As you are trying to add item on the top of the recyclerView, your positionStart will be 0 and itemCount is the number of items you are adding on top of the recyclerView.

Comment: Thanks Sifat, but no effect.

Comment: Have you tried DiffUtil ?
https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00

Comment: When you are using `notifyItemRangeInserted` you do not need to use this... `((LinearLayoutManager)mLayoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(index, top);`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I managed to solve it.

I used a list and in background thread added data in the end of this list.
But in RecyclerView I displayed data in reverse order. For this purpose I made invertion on items' indexes in my adapter (like this: invertedPosition = listSize - 1 - position).

And in this case I had a problem exactly like you described.

To solve it I made two changes:
1) Get rid of inversion of positions in my adapter;
2) turned on reverseLayout option in LinearLayoutManager (by setReverseLayout(true) call)

And, voila, everything worked as it should.

Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting data into the recycler view and want to stay at the top, you can add an AdapterDataObserver to your view adapter:

```
viewAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
        viewManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, 0)
    }
})
```